# How to use mapply to multiply each row of a data frame for an interval of rows of another data frame in R

Tags: r, mapply

I'm new to r and I have two huge data frames that I'm working on. What I need is to multiply each row of the first data frame for intervals of 5 rows of the second dataframe. In one file I have 305 respondents and for each respondent I have 60 profiles:

[image: file 1]

in the second file I have the same 305 respondents and for each I have 5 draws:

[image: file 2]

I want to multiply the columns with the same name in these files and sum them for participant 1, profile 1, draw 1; participant 1, profile 1, draw 2; participant 1, profile 1, draw 3; participant 1, profile 1, draw 4; participant 1, profile 1, draw 5; and so on for all the profiles for all the participants. So at the end I would get a column where, for instance, for row 1 (participant 1, draw 1, profile 1) I have a value of -0.23*1 + 0.92*1 + 1.72*0 =0.69 and for row 2 (participant 1, draw 2, profile 1) I have a value of -0.67*1 + 0.05*1 + 0.91*0= -0.62. For row 7 (participant 1, draw 1, profile 2) I want to multiply for the first draw again but the second profile, to have a value of -0.23*1 + 0.92*0 + 1.72*1= 1.18 and so on:

[image: desired output]

I tried with nested loops but it takes too much time, do you know how could I do this with mapply instead or some other function?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small input example instead of images (as we can't copy from image and test)

Comment: Please also include expected outcome whether calculated manually for the sample data/few rows/profiles at least, so as to make things clear.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added the outcome I would like to get, sorry this is a bit complicated! Hope it's better now.